# Creating a view in PostgresSQL for a query that worked in SQL Server (COUNT between two DATETIME columns/TIMECODE

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a problem with Redshift where it throws out a syntax error when trying to create a view similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM [Leads - leads]
     WHERE Receive_Time BETWEEN dbo.[Leads - extended spot summary fla32813].[Plan Air]
                            AND.dbo.[Leads - extended spot summary fla32813].[Plan End]) AS Leads 
INTO 
    [32813DA] 
FROM 
   .dbo.[Leads - extended spot summary fla32813]
`
```

Answer (score 3):

This code has numerous errors from a Redshift perspective:

- It is using square braces as delimiters.  Redshift (and the SQL Standard) is double quotes.
- The three-part naming doesn't look right for Redshift.
- `into` is not allowed in views in any of the mentioned databases.

You may have other errors as well, but you need to get the names right before you start with anything related to logic.

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT ... INTO ... syntax is specific to SQL Server and create a table from a SELECT. The ISO SQL syntax is CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT ...) but does not woks with SQL Server.

Use a more simple an sharable syntax like :

```
CREATE TABLE ??? (..);

INSERT INTO ???
SELECT ...
```